# What is the meaning of `sum [] = 0`?

Tags: haskell

```
sum :: [Int] -> Int
sum [] = 0
sum (x:xs) = x + sum xs
```

I do not understand what the purpose of the line `sum [] = 0` is. I found this piece of code in a textbook (it did not go into detail as to what this line does.)

Comment: Remove this line and rerun the code (call `sum` like `sum [1,2]`, for example) to see what's wrong

Comment: For an empty list, the sum is `0`, since we recurse on the list, eventually we will reach the empty list.

Comment: Are you asking why you need to define `sum` for empty lists, or why `sum []` is defined to equal 0?

Comment: Basically in `Monoid` type class `[]` is the identity element of the `List` type just like  `Sum 0` is the identity element of the `Sum` type where both are members of. So essentially `sum [1,2,3]` is like `getSum $ Sum 1 <> Sum 2 <> Sum 3 <> Sum 0`.

Answer (score 5):

`sum [] = 0` is the edge condition of the recursion.

Suppose we have `sum [1, 4, 6, 8]`.  The list can be rewritten as `1:4:6:8:[]`. The empty list is the last 'element'. The calculation is as follow `(1 + ( 4 + (6 + ( 8 + 0))))`. When all the elements of the list have been traversed, what remains is the empty list. Adds zero to the calculated result and ends the iteration.